# Ubuntu 16.04 run python script when login screen is displayed (rc.local and lightdm not working)

Tags: python, sudo, password, startup, etc

I want to run this command when the login screen that prompts for your password is displayed: `python ~/blabla/unlock.py &`. I've tried using both lightdm and rc.local to no avail. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because of the nature of interpeting language you need have to have working python shell to execute python scripts. If i dont get you wrong, you want to do run scripts before login, i mean before the running shell which is as i know imposibble because shell begins to run in user level. Am I wrong? +1

Comment: Or you just want to run when you login with username and password? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @al0s I stated that I wanted to run it at the password prompt screen.....

Comment: I am also programming in Python. I want to learn too if it is possible. Let's wait someone to answer it. Maybe this question makes more sense in stackexchange unix/linux part.

Comment: How exactly did you try to use lightdm to do this? what does the script do? how should the system interpret `~` before a user has logged in?

Comment: @steeldriver I copied to script into /bin so. The script is on a loop checking the usb port for a certain mass storage drive (using pyusb) and when it is inserted it uses xautomation to type my password into the password field.